# overlay View over AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer

Tags: ios, swift, camera, overlay, avcapturesession

Aim : To create an Overlay view over AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer in LandscapeRight orientation

Problem : Unable to fit the overlay view exactly over AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.
The width of the overlay that is being drawn is two times that of the screen.

This is my overlay View that i want to be drawn over the camera view

[image]

This is what i am able to achieve after doing the following.

[image]

My Code

```
    let previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: self.avCaptureSession)

    previewLayer.frame = self.view.layer.frame

    previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill

    self.view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)        

    let cameraOverlay = CameraOverlay(nibName:"CameraOverlay",bundle: nil)

    let cameraOverlayView:CameraOverlayView = cameraOverlay.view as! CameraOverlayView

    let previewView = UIView(frame: view.frame)

    self.view.addSubview(previewView)

    previewView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)

    self.view.addSubview(cameraOverlayView)

    self.avCaptureSession?.startRunning()
```